# Bulk move Java Classes to new package

Tags: java, automated-refactoring

I am willing to make a test on a Spring Application where context startup times have become way too slow. One approach is to make the package scan more strict, but then I will have to move all the bean implementations inside this stricter package structure (for example, from com.foo.* to com.foo.beans.*).

When I start the container, there are over 2500 beans scanned by Spring (implementations + Interfaces), so I am assuming I will have to move about 1000-1300 classes. The good thing is: I can easiliy generate a list of them during context startup...

However, I also want an automated refactoring using a list file as an input. Before I start writing some script that covers this task, is there anything on the market that can do this task? I am not so afraid about class calls from outside since basically all beans are injected beans, and only interfaces should be used to call them (if dip principle was applied correctly everywhere, but I will be able to deal with exceptions by hand!).

By the way, since first answers seem to show that I did not explain the problem enough: the files I have in the list are in different packages, and the packages might have other classes which I do not want to move. My best approach would be to find a way to call an eclipse refactoring to move a single file from location a to b, but that 1200 times in a row for files I do know. I will NOT do that per hand, and I have not found any tooling that would do this bulk task for me, although it is a perfectly automatable task which should not take more than a minute, but would take a whole day of clicking...

Answer (score 1):

> if you are using eclipse IDE
>   1. Right Click on project -> Refactor  ->  Rename
>   2. Right Click on project -> Refactor  ->  move
>
> or
>
> 1. select project by mouse click  and use shortcuts ( Alt + Shift  +  R ) -rename
> 2. select project by mouse click  and use shortcuts ( Alt + Shift  +  V ) -move

Comment: No, this would make me do it 100 times, not all classes are in the same package, and there might be other classes inside these packages which I do not want to move... For 10-20 classes this approach works, for 1000+ it would take 1-2 days to get all classes moved... I would need the automated refactoring from Eclipse for a single class, but call it autmatically 1000+ times...

Comment: Take a backup of your package and then delete all classes other than one group and refactor, once done paste second group refactor so continue.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring the package in an IDE like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) should do.

Comment: No, this would make me do it 100 times, not all classes are in the same package, and there might be other classes inside these packages which I do not want to move... For 10-20 classes this approach works, for 1000+ it would take 1-2 days to get all classes moved... I would need the automated refactoring from Eclipse for a single class, but call it autmatically 1000+ times...

Comment: Then what is the relation between the classes? Even if you'd want to write a script, the classes need to have a certain common move action.

Comment: All are in packages that start with com.foo, and as I said, I have a List of the 1000+ classes, and I just want to change a detail in package pattern. For instance move com.foo.* to com.foo.bar.*

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, but found there was no bulk solution. The only way I could do it was the following using IntelliJ

- First, try and move all code to the new namespace using `Refactor | Move`
- If anything is 3rd party, or generated, (ie not in your src/main or src/test) then dont move it, and move all other namespaces/classes inside the namespace using `Refactor | Move`, which you can do using multi select.
- Of course this will change what classes can be seen by your moved classes. e.g. if another lib was in the same namespace before, now it isn't, so they're not allowed access to things in the package without an explicit import.
- This may cause lots of `Error creating bean with name...` type errors. Probably you can get around most of these by adding `ComponentScan` to the class that's complaining, with both your old and new namespaces

  ```
  @ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.old.*", "com.mycompany.new.*"})
  ```
- If you have a Spring repository too, then  you may have the same issue happening with entities (`Not a managed type`). Resolve them the same way by adding the following to your main application.

  ```
  @EntityScan({"com.mycompany.old.*", "com.mycompany.new.*"})
  ```